# NullPointer exception on Adding TextView on onDraw

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view

I'm trying to add a textview in onDraw method of myCustomView class. So, if I do this it works without any issue,

```
tv = new TextView(context);
tv.setTextSize(14); 
tv.layout(left, top, right, bottom);
tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);  
tv.setText(text);
canvas.save(); 
canvas.translate(left, top);
tv.draw(canvas);
```

But I don't want to instantiate TextView in onDraw. So if I initialize TextView outside (of onDraw), in class constructor for example, then this code does work. It gives me following error,

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'int
>   android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams.width' on a null object reference
>                                                                                at android.widget.TextView.checkForRelayout(TextView.java:8447)
>                                                                                at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:5378)
>                                                                                at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:5234)
>                                                                                at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:5191)

What is the reason of this error?

Answer (score 3):

Why would you add a TextView in onDraw?  There's no good reason to do this, it will have HORRIBLE performance and isn't needed.  If you want to draw text in onDraw, use canvas.drawText().  If you want to add a textView, do it in a normal place.  Do't do it in rendering, a part of the app that needs to be as fast as possible.  Your onDraw should avoid creating objects at all if possible, much less creating something as heavyweight as a View.

Also, trying to add that view-  you didn't do it right.  You have to add it to a parent view, then let that parent layout.  Right after a new it isn't part of a View hierarchy, so it won't draw to the screen.  The specific crash you got is because it hasn't been added to a view hierarchy so it has no layout params.  But don't try to fix that-  just don't add a View here, use drawText or add the View elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I'm tying to understand some old code.